# If $\alpha$ is a plane curve, we may assume (by appropriate choice of coordinates in $\mathbf{R}^3$) that $\alpha$ lies in the $(x,y)$ planes.

Tags: differential-geometry

This question comes from the textbook " Elemnets of Differential geometry" by R.S. Millman and G.D. Parker page 31, in the process of proving corollary 4.3

> If $\alpha$ is a plane curve, we may assume (by appropriate  choice of coordinates in $\mathbf{R}^3$) that $\alpha$ lies in the $(x,y)$ planes.

I don't understand what this stands for. 
Can anybody explain this sentence more precisely?

Comment: You can rotate and translate the coordinate system so that the plane curve is contained in any particular plane you may want.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez, you mean that if $\alpha$ is a plane curve, by rotating or translating the coordinate system i can make the $\alpha$ lies in $(x,y)$ or $(y,z)$.. $(x,z)$... like any other plane?

Comment: That is precisely what I wrote :-)

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez, Thanks,  From the Linear transformation of coordinate system ($i.e$, rotation, translation) i can assume above statement, clearly.